# Calculating n for Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm comparing two samples using python's `scipy.stats.ks_2samp` which returns a D value and P value. How do you calculate `n` for the two samples to use on the D value lookup table?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by `n` ?

Comment: I mean the size of the sample that you use in the lookup table for the one-sample test. [lookup table](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~schwaar/Exercises/Tabellen/table_kolmogorov.pdf)

Comment: If samples are of M and N size; n will be M+ N - 2 for your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to make an ill-posed comparison. The statistic for the two-samples case is not the same as the one-sample case and also the critical value is calculated differently.

In the two-samples case, if $D_{n,m}$ is the K-S statistic, where $n$ the size of the first sample and $m$ that of the second one, you reject the hypothesis "$H_0$: the two samples have the same distribution" if 
$$ D_{n,m} > c(\alpha)\sqrt{\dfrac{n+m}{nm}},$$
where $c(\alpha) = \sqrt{-\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)},$ and $\alpha$ your chosen level of significance.

Comment: Apparently the user is interested in knowing the degrees of freedom for looking into  the critical value .